# Sort items in a table view in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application in which i am displaying the result of web service in table view, now i want to display according to the selection.
for example.
there are certain items such as price, description, title.
now if i want to display all the result according to price how should i display.
I have used XML parsing to display the result in table view.

Please give me the proper solution for this.
Awaiting for your positive reply.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `NSSortDescriptor` for each way you want to sort the data in the `tableview`.  Each time your choose a different way to sort, your datasource is going to have to refresh.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it) as this questions has been answered many times.